# java else if. not sure where im going wrong

Tags: java

I keep getting else without if. Any ideas why? Thanks all. By the way i'm a student so please bear with me.

```
public class QuizGrading
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int grade = 100;     
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        grade.input.in.nextlnt();
        { 
            System.out.print("Please enter grade");
        }
        if (grade >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("You have been graded  A");
        }
        else if (grade <= 80 && >= 89) 
        {
            System.out.println("You have been graded B");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: While fixing up your formatting, I noticed that you had an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'else without if'?  Do you mean a compilation error?  Or are you hitting the else block when you don't expect to?  Also, you have `if (A >= 90)`, which must be causing problems.  Guessing you mean `if (grade >= 90)`

Comment: else if (grade <= 80 && >= 89)

Comment: The above is the problem when i try and compile it.

Comment: There should be a problem with `grade.input.in.nextlnt()` already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the in varible into grade variable and change the inside of if condition with grade variable.  It will be helpful if you see online java tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

Try `else if (grade <= 80 && grade >= 89)` instead of `else if (grade <= 80 && >= 89)`. Note the **grade** variable being referenced on the right side of the expression.

Comment: Its giving me the same problem :-(

Comment: @user380603, it's giving you the same problem because there are _no_ numbers that are both less than 81 and greater than 88 :-) See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your problematic line is:

```
else if (grade <= 80 && >= 89)
```

This is invalid syntax which can be fixed with the insertion of `grade` in the second half:

```
else if (grade <= 80 && grade >= 89)
```

However, I'd like you to tell me what number is both less than or equal to 80 *and* greater than or equal to 89 at the same time. It's been quite a while since I did my university courses but I don't think basic mathematics has changed *that* drastically :-) I thin what you *meant* to say is:

```
else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
```

but see below for a better solution.

You have a few problems in that code that need fixing.

1. You ask for the user input *after* you accept it. Your `Please enter grade` should come before the scanner input. You also ask within a block, which is unnecessary here.
2. Your first `if` statement checks some mythical `A` variable rather than the correct `grade`.
3. Your `else if` is the wrong sense, as already mentioned. This can be fixed by reversing the `<=` and `>=` symbols but, since you're already in the `else` bit, it means you're *not* `>= 90` so you can just get away with the lower bounds check.
4. You appear to be calling `nextlnt` (with a lower-case `l` rather than an upper-case `I`.
5. It's usually a good idea to finish off with a default `else` so you can see what's really happening in your code.

Fixing those problems gives you something like:

```
public class QuizGrading
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int grade = 100;     
        System.out.print("Please enter grade");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        grade.input.in.nextInt();

        if (grade >= 90)
        {
            System.out.println("You have been graded  A");
        }
        else if (grade >= 80) 
        {
            System.out.println("You have been graded B");
        } else {
            // As many else-if statements as required.
            System.out.println("You have been graded C or less");
        }
    }    
}
```